# How can I set the next value of a serial for the serial used by the primary key of a table in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have Table A. Table A owns a sequence.
I create Table B, inheriting from Table A.
Table A and B now use the same default value for their primary key column.
For a simplified example, Table A is "person", and B is "bulk_upload_person".

```
CREATE TABLE "testing"."person" (
  "person_id" serial, --Resulting DDL: int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('person_person_id_seq'::regclass)
  "public" bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false
);

--SQL Ran
CREATE TABLE "testing"."bulk_upload_person" (
    "upload_id" int4 NOT NULL
)
INHERITS ("testing"."person");

--Resulting DDL
CREATE TABLE "testing"."bulk_upload_person" (
    "person_id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('person_person_id_seq'::regclass),
    "public" bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    "upload_id" int4 NOT NULL
)
INHERITS ("testing"."person");
```

For table A, I can get the sequence by using `pg_get_table_serial_seqence`.
How can I get and then set the next value of the sequence if I only know about Table B? I want to add n to the value.

I need to do this in order to populate multiple related objects at once, while being able to know what primary IDs they will have, rather than having to query the tables I've just populated to determine the IDs.

By populate, I mean inserting multiple rows in one statement.

```
insert into "testing"."bulk_upload_person" ( "person_id", "public", "upload_id") values ( '1', 'f', '1'), ( '2', 't', '1'); --etc
```

I think our situation is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8007835/89211 but we don't want to keep the lock on the table beyond getting and setting the next value of the serial for each table.

Currently we are doing this by getting the name of the sequence by regexing the default value of the primary key for Table B, but it feels like there's probably a better way to do this that we don't realise.

Comment: `Table B, inheriting from Table A. Table A and B now use the same default value for their primary key column.` The same *value*, or the same *sequence* to supply the default value? -->> please show us the DDL. `By populate, I mean pgsql COPY.` -->> Show us the copy statement you try to use.

Comment: Sure. We are using an ORM. We assumed it was copy, but it's a bulk insert in stead. I'll update the question to reflect.